# Python look up value in same week, different product

Tags: python, pandas

Using python data frames, I want to find the volume of different products and get them together in one line. The basic is like this:

| Week | Product | Volume |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Drink | 5 |
| 2 | Drink | 5 |
| 1 | Burger | 3 |
| 2 | Burger | 2 |
| 3 | Drink | 10 |
| 3 | Burger | 4 |

And I would like the output to be like this. Where the volume of the product of that week is obvious, but I don't know how else to visualize this. The goal is to see if in the week where we had a promotion on drinks and sold 10, the sale of burgers also went up.

The only thing is this is divided over 4 stores, 2 products and 5 variants per product.

| Week | Product | Volume | Volume Burger | Volume Drink |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Drink | 5 | 3 | 5 |
| 2 | Drink | 5 | 2 | 5 |
| 1 | Burger | 3 | 3 | 5 |
| 2 | Burger | 2 | 2 | 5 |
| 3 | Drink | 10 | 4 | 10 |
| 3 | Burger | 4 | 10 | 4 |

What I tried:
First tried with `groupby` Product/Week and use shift. But this does not work with multiple products.

Then tried something like this:

```
data['Volume Burgers'] = data['Volume'].loc[('Product' == 'Burger') & ('Week' == 'Week')]
```

Comment: I think you have an error in the last line of your output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, use a combination of `pivot` and `merge`:

```
df.merge(df.pivot(index='Week', columns='Product', values='Volume')
           .add_prefix('Volume '),
         left_on='Week', right_index=True)
```

output:

```
   Week  Product  Volume  Volume Burger   Volume Drink 
0     1   Drink        5               3              5
2     1  Burger        3               3              5
1     2   Drink        5               2              5
3     2  Burger        2               2              5
4     3   Drink       10               4             10
5     3  Burger        4               4             10
```

Comment: I ended up using pivot_table, because I got an error about there being duplicates in my index. But it worked beautifully. Thank you.

Comment: @Isidora yes, `pivot` requires unique indices, however be careful to chose which aggregation function you want in `pivot_table` as this is performing a **mean** by default (**sum** might be better in your case?)

Comment: In this case I think it does not matter because there is only 1 line per week, per product, so mean/sum/min/max all comes to the same number. But good to keep in mind for future reference.